# How can i remove envira gallery button in post create and edit?

Tags: wordpress

I have tried adminizer plugin to show and hide other buttons but i didnt get any option to hide add gallery button for post.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

`add_filter( 'envira_gallery_media_button', 'remove_envira_gallery_media_button' );
function remove_envira_gallery_media_button( $button ) {
    return '';
}`

Just tried it and it works.

Before:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MIzniQ4P5o-lvUkM-Hrgk4eGRHozC744

After:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xq7g1QKuxrSgcYiB-P9NQhsqSz9way6g

Found answer here: 
https://gist.github.com/ericakfranz/21d6e28970e236403197e75092400166